# place an id in the middle of a haml line

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

What I want to achieve is this..

A line that shows as

```
Comments (32)
```

Where 32 is the count of comments against a post. Now this is easily achieved in haml with

```
%h2 Comments (#{Post.count_of_comments})
```

however, I am creating and deleting comments with AJAX and javascript. I need to be able to place an identifier against the count so that I can adjust it in the javascript. Obviously, I could do

```
#count
  %h2 Comments (#{Post.count_of_comments})
```

but is there any way of putting an id tag against just the count rather than the whole line, or failing that how would I identify that count in javascript.

Comment: Mark the comments with a CSS class, and count them using jQuery.  `var numItems = $('.yourclass').length`

Comment: yes, sorry, I'm actually asking HOW to mark with a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply an ID to the h2 itself like so:

```
%h2#count Comments (#{Post.count_of_comments})
```

Or apply a span to the count:

```
%h2 Comments
    %span#count (#{Post.count_of_comments})
```

You could also add the parens via CSS, if you just want to plug in a raw number with your Javascript:

```
%h2 Comments
    %span#count #{Post.count_of_comments}
```

CSS:

```
#count:before {
    content: "(";
}

#count:after {
    content: ")";
}
```

JS:

```
var newCount = 42;
$('#count').html(newCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the trick??

```
%h2
  Comments
  = surround '(', ')' do
    %span#custom-id
      = Post.count_of_comments
```